# How to access current size of HashTable from another class in Java

Tags: java, size, hashtable, hashcode

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to implement my own hashcode and equals functions for a class called Book. The hashtable has its own abstract class called ProbingHashTable (there are also other classes for implementing different types of probing that extends the ProbingHashTable class, for another part of the assignment).

I would like to include `key % tableSize` (among other things) in the hashcode function if possible. The ProbingHashTable has a size() function, but of course the size can change if the hashtable gets rehashed etc. Is it possible to access the current size of the table from the Book class somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat unclear what you want, but it seems like you want to change what you return in `hashCode` based on some state unrelated to the object `hashCode` is being called on.

That's tricky to do and, more importantly, almost certainly breaking [the contract of `hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). If you check that documentation the first requirement for `hashCode` is:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified

This means that your `hashCode` method *must not* consider any data that isn't also considered in the `equals` method. And since "the size of a map that is mostly unrelated to this object" isn't anything that should be used in your `equals` method it's **definitely** not something that you should use in your `hashCode`.

You *could* hold a reference to the map in your `Book` class and just query the current size in the `hashCode` method, but it's bound to cause a good number of issues and not really do anything good for you.

That being said: the calculation you describe (like `key % tableSize`) is usually done in **the map implementation** *after* the `hashCode` method was called.

In other words: it's perfectly fine if the *map* implementation (or whoever gets and uses the `hashCode` result) further manipulates the return value to fit its requirements. And that's what you probably should work towards.